# How do I beat the dinosaur in Tricky's Mountain?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing

I can't beat the boss of the first world (Dino Domain). Are there any specific tactics I should use, such as charging the boosts and rockets, or firing off the level 1 versions? Does he speed up if he's behind me, or does he slow down if I get too far behind?

[image: The first boss]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He does slow down quite a bit right before the finish line, so that is a good spot to overtake him if you are close behind him. Other than that, his speed doesn't really vary, ahead or behind.

Also, try not to let him step on you - when you are flattened, you lose a lot of valuable time.

There is also a shortcut of sorts that you can use - it is marked by a set of bushes. You can also recognize it ahead of time by the rock outcropping and a blue balloon nearby.

If you get the boost at the start, you'll be ahead of the Triceratops.

Also, if you are behind the Triceratops, homing missiles are a good way to get ahead of him.

Getting the blue balloons (if possible, some of them can be tricky) are your best bet to get ahead of him quickly, and to extend your lead once you have it.

Answer (score 1):

just a little tip i've seen that if you tap the accelerate button insted of holding it you go a bit faster.
link here:

Answer (score 0):

Blue balloons if you can, I would not recommend using *homing* rockets, you should have the accuracy to hit him with single-balloon non-homing rockets.

As mentioned in the other answer, the shortcut is also nice. However, please do note that you do not gain anything from this in the "second" mode, since there will not be a zipper there.

Also, I like characters with easy handling on this track (Tipsy or Tiptup). The sceenshot shows Banjo, which I find hard to use to beat this boss.